# How to convert Blob data to string in Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I am using Arcpy to load a table from Excel. One of the fields has a lot of text (up to 2000 characters) and when using arcpy.MakeTableView_management the field is given the type 'BLOB'. Is there any way to either prevent this from happening, i.e. making sure the field type is 'Text', or is there a way of reading the text in python so the data can be used?

I have read [BLOB TYPE in Arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159486/blob-type-in-arcmap) but it does not answer the question. I am specifically trying to read the data in Python, while the previous question referred to reading it in ArcMap.

Comment: How is this *not* a duplicste of the referenced question?

Comment: I am specifically trying to read the data in Python, while the previous question referred to reading it in ArcMap

Comment: If it were an option, it would have been documented; therefore you need to write some code. What have you written so far?

Comment: I have been able to extract individual characters using memoryview():

`rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Table","Comments")
for row in rows:
 memview = memoryview(row[0])
 print memview[2]`

Comment: Please [edit] your question for any requested clarifications.

Comment: Did you check out a link in the referenced answer, which is http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/working-with-blob-data-at-101-arcpyda.html

Comment: [Excel To Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/excel-to-table.htm) will convert the field to text (while e.g. [Table To Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-table.htm) will convert it to BLOB). You could try to save the output of Excel To Table `in_memory` if you don't want an intermediate result on disk.

Comment: As yet another option, you could use a python library to read the excel file.  Here is a listing of some libraries that work with excel: http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: Excel to Table has worked for saving the table to a geodatabase, however if I try using `in_memory` I get the error message: `indexError: string index out of range Failed to execute (ExcelToTable).`

Comment: and thank you for all your suggestions, I am gradually getting there!

Comment: I have also had to use `encode` as not all characters were recognized from the text
`comments = row.getValue("Comments").encode('utf8')`

Answer (score 1):

[Reading Blobs:](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com/2012/06/working-with-blob-data-at-101-arcpyda.html)

```
from arcpy import da
import os
with da.SearchCursor(r"c:\temp\demo.gdb\table",['blobFieldname','fileName']) as cursor:
   for row in cursor:
      binaryRep = row[0]
      fileName = row[1]
      # save to disk
      open(r"c:\saveFolder" + os.sep + fileName, 'wb').write(binaryRep.tobytes())
      del row
      del binaryRep
      del fileName
```